# How to release memory, allocated by RtlQueryRegistryValues in Windows kernel driver

Tags: windows, kernel, driver

Function RtlQueryRegistryValues can allocate memory for returning REG_SZ result.
Everything works nicely, but I cannot guess how to release that memory.
Code fragment:

```
UNICODE_STRING result;
RtlZeroMemory(&result, sizeof(UNICODE_STRING));

RTL_QUERY_REGISTRY_TABLE queryTable[2];
queryTable[0].Flags = RTL_QUERY_REGISTRY_DIRECT | . . .;
queryTable[0].EntryContent = &result;
. . .

RtlQueryRegistryValues(..., queryTable, NULL, NULL);
```

All fields of `result` are populated correctly. I am trying to find out how to deallocate results.Buffer.
As a workaround, I can allocate sufficient buffer myself before calling the function, but I am looking for clean solution.
Thanks==

Comment: have you tried ExFreePool()? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-exfreepool

Comment: or RtlFreeUnicodeString() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlfreeunicodestring

Comment: @Baget - thanks, ExitFreePool(result.Buffer) did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can [ExFreePool()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-exfreepool) to free memory. but since it is a Unicode string you should try also [RtlFreeUnicodeString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlfreeunicodestring)